# How do you add embeds in the discord.py module

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am using replit and this is my code so far:

```
TOKEN = os.environ['TOKEN']
client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("bot online") 
    

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.content == "!Help":
    embedVar = discord.Embed(title="Title", description="Desc", color=0x00ff00)
    embedVar.add_field(name="Field1", value="hi", inline=False)
    embedVar.add_field(name="Field2", value="hi2", inline=False)
    await message.channel.send(message.channel, Embed=embed)



client.run(TOKEN)
```

It returns an error message saying "embed" is not defined. I just copied this of a site, after looking for an hour so I do not know much so if somebody could explain to me how to fix this and how use embeds id appreciate it. I think I am a version below 1 but im not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined your embed as `embedVar` so you need to pass that in when you send the message. Also since you are already using `message.channel.send`, the `message.channel` argument will be useless.

```py
await message.channel.send(embed=embedVar)
```